# How to handle group by automatically with PGSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have to do calculations on my database. When I was using mysql, it wasn't a problem, but now that I use PGSQL, I see the following issue :

I have 3 tables : dogs, users and dogs_users, the join table (it's a n-n, every dog can have multiple users and every user can have multiple dogs)

When I do the following :

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > User.first.dogs.group(:name).average(:number_of_fleas)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "dogs.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT     "dogs".*, AVG("dogs"."number_of_fleas") AS "avera...
                   ^
: SELECT     "dogs".*, AVG("dogs"."number_of_fleas") AS "average_number_of_fleas", name AS name FROM       "dogs"  INNER JOIN "dogs_users" ON "dogs".id = "dogs_users".dog_id WHERE     (("dogs_users".user_id = 1)) GROUP BY  name
```

The only work around I found to handle the problem was to do the following :

```
Dog.where(:id => User.first.dogs.map(&:id)).group(:name).average(:number_of_fleas)
```

And that's not very readable nor very optimized...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct on if you don't care which of the multiple values you get back:

select distinct on (col1, col2) col1, col2, col3 from sometable;

Note that you could get any value for col3 here.